# how to change hooks, brackets using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to change brackets, in the code after tags 
using jQuery. I can not understand how.

```
<section> 
<a href="/"></a>  
» 
<a class="dateBar" href="/"></a>  
» 
<a class="dateBar" href="/"></a>  
» 
<a class="dateBar" href="/"></a>  
» 
</ section>
```

Comment: How do you want to code to look after jQuery has been applied?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do, as your question is not at all clear.

Comment: I want to change the brackets after the closing </ a> everywhere after him, but I can not get access to the full code can I use jquery change them?

Comment: These brackets after the tag ">>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `html()` jQuery method can accept a function that can be used to change the html of any matching elements. The return value is substituted.

You can then combine it with a regex replace (with the /g global option) and it will do all the replacements quite fast.

e.g.

```
$('section').html(function(){return $(this).html().replace(/»/g, "&gt;")});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vh3etp6q/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('section').contents().each(function(inedx, el) {
    if(el.nodeType == 3 && el.textContent.indexOf('»') != -1){
        $(el).replaceWith('a');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that is necessary.